# Group column with the same subheader name in datatable using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table like this

[image]

In which I have different city where we have demand-supply of different products.

Now what I want  as here demand is different for all the products However supply is the same on all of three product, so I want that table looks like in this manner.

[image]

What I want to do is I want only to show the supply column once in the last of the table. This has to be done dynamically as in the future we have multiple products

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

What the code below does is:

- Identify the positions of the "Supply"'s and store them in `ind` array, in this case will be `[3, 5, 7]`
- Loops through `ind` except for the last element `7`(as one "Supply" will be left) and hide all `td`'s; `$("td:nth-child("3")`, `$("td:nth-child("5")`
- The "Demand"s that precede each of these elements will be assigned two spaces.

```js
      let ind = [];
      $("td:contains('Supply')").each(function (index) {
        ind.push($(this).index() + 1);
      });

      $(".hide").on("click", function () {
        for (let i = 0; i < ind.length - 1; i++) {
          let el = $("td:nth-child(" + ind[i] + ")");
          el.prev().attr("colspan", "2");
          el.hide();
        }
      });
```

```css
      table,
      th,
      td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>City</th>
        <th colspan="2">Product 1</th>
        <th colspan="2">Product 2</th>
        <th colspan="2">Product 3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Demand</td>
        <td>Supply</td>
        <td>Demand</td>
        <td>Supply</td>
        <td>Demand</td>
        <td>Supply</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>City 1</td>
        <td>50$</td>
        <td>60$</td>
        <td>90$</td>
        <td>60$</td>
        <td>100$</td>
        <td>60$</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>City 2</td>
        <td>50$</td>
        <td>60$</td>
        <td>90$</td>
        <td>60$</td>
        <td>100$</td>
        <td>60$</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>City 3</td>
        <td>50$</td>
        <td>60$</td>
        <td>90$</td>
        <td>60$</td>
        <td>100$</td>
        <td>60$</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>City 4</td>
        <td>50$</td>
        <td>60$</td>
        <td>90$</td>
        <td>60$</td>
        <td>100$</td>
        <td>60$</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <button class="hide">Hide</button>
```